# Uso de "malogrado"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Estoy leyendo [la reseña](http://www.rfea.es/web/noticias/desarrollo.asp?codigo=12080) que ha publicado la RFEA sobre el Campeonato de España de Atletismo, que se ha celebrado este pasado fin de semana, y me encuentro con esta frase:

> En decatlón, Pablo Trescolí ha sido el ganador final con 7.673 puntos por delante de Jesús Castillo (7.359) y Mario Arancón (7187) y que junto a sus compañeros tuvieron al final un bonito recuerdo para el malogrado Jorge Ureña.

Ureña, el favorito para el triunfo en la prueba de decatlón, se lesionó a mitad de prueba y no pudo terminar. Pero a mí la palabra *malogrado* me hace pensar otra cosa. ¿Es un uso correcto el que se hace en el párrafo citado? La [definición del RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=O3d8nXo) no me aporta mucha luz, la verdad.

(La gramática de la frase en cuestión podría ser objeto de otro debate, pero aquí solo me interesa el uso de la palabra *malogrado*).

Comment: no das mucha información sobre lo que piensas que significa *malogrado* o porque las definiciones del DLE no te cuadran. Algo que se malogra es algo que fracasa o que no llega al resultado esperado, en este caso el tal Ureña siendo el favorito no solo no ganó sino que ni siquiera pudo terminar la carrera.

Comment: Es raro el uso de "malogrado" con sustantivos propios. Me parece que sería más natural y habitual usarlo con un sustantivo común, en cuyo caso el significado sería que la persona no alcanzó el nivel esperado para esa profesión (el DRAE habla de la imposibilidad de desarrollarse o perfeccionarse). Así, podríamos hablar de "el malogrado atleta".

Comment: @walen Tienes razón. Se dice, por ejemplo, "el malogrado Kennedy".

Comment: @blonfu No quería condicionaros con mis ideas; prefería ver qué entendíais vosotros. Pero lo que pienso está en línea con lo que explica walen en su respuesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con base en la tercera entrada de la definición del DLE que has enlazado:

> 3. prnl. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: No llegar a su natural desarrollo o perfeccionamiento.

Te iba a responder que lo veía un uso correcto: Jorge Ureña era el favorito; lo natural era que ganase la carrera; no la ganó, por tanto no ha llegado a su natural desarrollo, por tanto... ¿se ha malogrado?

**Pues no.** No está bien usada esa palabra ahí, porque conlleva un matiz importante: el de *estado final*. Un fatalismo que no se puede obviar.

Algo que se ha "logrado" es algo que está completo, algo finalizado, algo que se consigue llevar a su mayor grado de perfeccionamiento. Algo cuyo estado final ha sido alcanzado, y es bueno.
**Hablar de "malogrado" es como hablar del gemelo malvado de "logrado"**: cuando estamos persiguiendo un objetivo y el **resultado final** no es lo que queríamos; cuando la tarea se queda incompleta; cuando no se consiguieron alcanzar el desarrollo o perfección esperados. Cuando el estado al que finalmente se ha llegado, no es bueno.

No es por tanto "malogrado" algo "no logrado" *todavía*, sino algo más: una sentencia sobre el futuro de quien se habla, un lamento por lo que pudo ser y ya *nunca* será.

Por eso el espacio natural de "malogrado" cuando se aplica a personas son las noticias sobre accidentes mortales, lesiones incapacitantes, problemas de drogas, suicidios y demás eventos desgraciados: porque suelen conllevar un hachazo *definitivo* a las aspiraciones de la persona malograda, a lo que se esperaba de ella. El malogrado Jules Bianchi. La malograda María de Villota. El malogrado Brandon Lee. La malograda Janis Joplin.

Jorge Ureña se lesionó y no pudo siquiera empezar la carrera, cierto. Pero no es una lesión importante: [solo tiene una contractura](https://as.com/masdeporte/2019/09/01/atletismo/1567331858_890308.html). Sin duda, su victoria en la competición se malogró. Quizá se malogre su temporada también. Pero, salvo que esta lesión le cause una depresión que lo aparte de la competición para siempre, **no podemos decir que Jorge Ureña se haya malogrado**.

Comment: Y, efectivamente, se hizo una contractura o algo parecido; al menos, lo que anunció su entrenador fue una lesión leve, pero que le impedía participar en el segundo día de la prueba. Veo que entiendes la palabra como yo, aunque das una explicación mejor de la que tenía. A ver si alguien más responde, pero esta me parece una buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En mi interpretación el adjetivo sobre Ureña está correctamente usado en la frase en cuestión, entendiéndose el término "*malogrado*" en el sentido de [*frustrarse lo que se pretendía conseguir*](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/malograr) Al margen de la construcción gramatical o de la concisión estilística, la alusión hecha a Ureña resulta comprensible y en linea con esa acepción. Es sin duda suya la frustración por no haber podido correr una carrera tan importante cuyo triunfo le era asequible (dada su condición de favorito)

El saludo de sus rivales aparece subsidiario de esa idea, es una muestra de respeto que trasunta un gesto de empatía hacia el decatleta español, impedido de participar por una lesión y por lo tanto privado del protagonismo al que estaba llamado en la competencia.

*Las pruebas de recuperación son mañana; los reprobados (Lopez, Galindez y Herrera) tienen una chance más en el horario de las diez*

¿Por qué entendemos la frase?

Sabemos que fueron sus exámenes los reprobados, no los alumnos mismos (por el contenido insuficiente, confuso o  erroneo de sus respuestas de acuerdo a la evaluación de un profesor); aun así, tenemos naturalizada la economia del lenguaje que abrevia, acorta camino y nombra a los estudiantes con el atributo del resultado de sus desempeños inmediatos en la materia examinada.
 Allí ocurre una operación que hace, por extensión, a los sujetos los poseedores del calificativo de sus exámenes fallidos. ¿Son los alumnos mismos unos reprobado e incapaces? No, no es un juicio de valor absoluto sobre sus vidas, o la opinion que muchas personas, la sociedad toda tenga sobre ellos. Les cabe eso en el contexto relativo a la perfomance en la prueba anterior

Comment: Pero, siguiendo los ejemplos de la página que enlazas, lo que se malogró no fue Ureña, sino su intento de ganar el decatlón o de conseguir la mínima para el Mundial.

Comment: Es cierto, pero aunque el adjetivo aplica a la participación frustada del atleta, (su protagonismo esperado y hasta su triunfo  probable en la carrera) hay un salto poético en eso que hace entendible aplicarselo al estado de su persona. Privado de ese logro al alcance y en el contexto del _bonito recuerdo_ de sus compañeros lo del _"al malogrado Urueña"_ se comprende bien como **al portante de la entendible frustación**

Comment: Es parte de la economía y belleza de la lengua (y la razón por la que los escritos legales no se atesoran entre los legados de arte y la expresión humana)